# While hitting the Serive , Java.net.socketException rises

Tags: android, wcf

Am facing this issue in android studio .... i have done a web service and given to the android team to use it and then the issues rises when they hitting the web service ..Can anyone has faced this issue i need to resolve it kindly respond, thanks in advance

Comment: Several possible causes. Can we have code?

Comment: Please share your code snippet or which issue faced by the android team.?

Comment: while they are hitting the web service i have written the following error has been thrown ..!    Java.Net.SocketException Connection Reset